# How include files just when need them?

Tags: javascript, laravel, optimization

I am using Laravel, sending Ajax requests to server.
But I don't need some libraries like **DropzoneJS** (a library for Ajax uploading ), some images, some functions before some Ajax requests.

Is there any way to include them after some actions?
*for example include a library when an element clicked*

Is there any library to do this job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to pre-load required stuff you can use `requirejs` for that purpose.
Keep in mind that using it will "hold" your code until all the requirements are for-filled.

If you need to do some stuff after the AJAX is completed you can use promises or callbacks to capture the response and do what ever you need to do.

Comment: oh, Thanks for your good behavior. I really don't know Can I use require.js for this purpose ? What do you think about it?

Comment: The problem with require is that you will need **all** the dependencies before continuing

Comment: I assume you have mistake in your original question: **But I don't need some libraries like**, i understand that you do need it.

Comment: oh yes sorry, **But I don't need some libraries like**  means I don't need that libraries and some files before Ajax send. I need them after Ajax

Comment: So you can use the jquery ajax phases to do stuff after the ajax is returned

Comment: No I will return an form with php to the ajax request, and I have more than 10 different forms and each of them have different fields and actions **And lots of Javscript and CSS code**